# Does Durarara have NSFW scenes?

Tags: durarara

I wanted to know if Durarara!! has NSFW scenes because I am thinking in watch the show in my tv in the living room. It would be very embarrassing if someone enters the room in the wrong time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you're counting with Durarara x2, but as far as I remember, there's at least on scene less appropriate to see in *public* ( with public, I mean not covered ). It's not anything showing off, but rather some actions between two characters.

Answer (score 3):

Two things we have to straighten out here:

1. There's nothing pornographic in this show; it's a show aimed at teenagers and young adults who can deal with the themes, action, and suggestive scenes contained within.
2. It's unfair to say it's "NSFW" when you're in your own living room.  What you do in your living room (within reason, so long as you're an adult) isn't that big of a deal.

That said...if you're worried about the embarrassment of watching this show, it may be best simply not to watch it in the living room.  This isn't to say that there's anything that would make you blush and *want* to watch it by yourself, but...

- ...there is a dullahan whose head is the *constant* subject of camera shots,
- ...there's a vivisectomy performed during the run of the series (in one episode),
- ...there's *constant* themes of violence, corruption, drugs and murder - without spoiling too much, that's ***literally*** one of the characters' reason for being around, and if you thought that wasn't enough,
- ...the show does get psychologically creepy and sexually suggestive, and these themes aren't exactly hard to miss.

If you're not sure that your family or others around you can handle or respect the themes in the show, then do what you can to avoid their discomfort and displeasure and watch in private.

Answer (score -1):

Through your inquiries, i can be sure that you got already be caught up watching a NSFW anime!
More seriously, yeah in durarara! x2 there have a certain scene *cough* *cough* but don't worry this is really short!

Comment: This answer doesn't add any new insight to the existing answers...